# Java -- ++ in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I am confused about the difference between this 3 statement.
What differences between each of them? I know the differences between first and third, but how different is between first and second, and second to third.

```
// first
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (count[s.charAt(i)]-- > 0) {
        tLen--;
    }
}

// second
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    count[s.charAt(i)]--;
    if (count[s.charAt(i)] > 0) {
        tLen--;
    }
}


// third
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    
    if (count[s.charAt(i)] > 0) {
        count[s.charAt(i)]--;
        tLen--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increment and Decrement operators in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905747/increment-and-decrement-operators-in-java)

Comment: 1 vs 2 - no practical difference.  2 vs 3 - difference is that 2 always decrements the counter but 3 only decrements the counter if it is > 0.  *This can all be deduced by **careful** reading of the code.*  If you can't "read" it, try [hand executing](https://www.programming4beginners.com/tutorial/chapter04/execution-by-hand) it; e.g. with a pencil and paper.

Comment: I **strongly** suggest to use `++` and `--` (together with their operands) as standalone expressions, and **never** combine them with other statements (like `if` or `for`). Combining them leads only to confusion of many.

Answer (score 2):

1. Decrement value but compare not decremented value

> if (count[s.charAt(i)]-- > 0) {

2. Decrement value and compare the decremented value

> count[s.charAt(i)]--;
> if (count[s.charAt(i)] > 0) {

3. Compare not decremented value and potentially decrement

> if (count[s.charAt(i)] > 0) {
> count[s.charAt(i)]--;